# Resource Calendar does not automatically cancel conflicting meetings in Office 365

Tags: powershell, office365

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. We have a room that I'd like to cancel a meeting whenever it conflicts with another in that room. In its current state, it does not even send the user a message alerting them of the conflict.

Here is my Get-CalendarProcessing. I have AllowConflicts set to false, ConflictPercentageAllowed and MaximumConflictInstances both at 0.

Thank you.

```
AutomateProcessing                   : AutoAccept
AllowConflicts                       : False
AllowDistributionGroup               : True
AllowMultipleResources               : True
BookingType                          : Standard
BookingWindowInDays                  : 366
MaximumDurationInMinutes             : 1440
MinimumDurationInMinutes             : 0
AllowRecurringMeetings               : True
EnforceAdjacencyAsOverlap            : False
EnforceCapacity                      : False
EnforceSchedulingHorizon             : True
ScheduleOnlyDuringWorkHours          : False
ConflictPercentageAllowed            : 0
MaximumConflictInstances             : 0
ForwardRequestsToDelegates           : True
DeleteAttachments                    : True
DeleteComments                       : True
RemovePrivateProperty                : True
DeleteSubject                        : True
AddOrganizerToSubject                : True
DeleteNonCalendarItems               : True
TentativePendingApproval             : True
EnableResponseDetails                : True
OrganizerInfo                        : True
ResourceDelegates                    : {}
RequestOutOfPolicy                   : {}
AllRequestOutOfPolicy                : False
BookInPolicy                         : {}
AllBookInPolicy                      : True
RequestInPolicy                      : {}
AllRequestInPolicy                   : False
AddAdditionalResponse                : False
AdditionalResponse                   :
RemoveOldMeetingMessages             : True
AddNewRequestsTentatively            : True
ProcessExternalMeetingMessages       : False
RemoveForwardedMeetingNotifications  : False
AutoRSVPConfiguration                : Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.AutoRSVPConfiguration
RemoveCanceledMeetings               : True
EnableAutoRelease                    : False
PostReservationMaxClaimTimeInMinutes : 10
MailboxOwnerId                       : Training Room
Identity                             : Training Room
IsValid                              : True
ObjectState                          : Changed
```

Comment: Is there any PowerShell code?